# MVC5 How to filter for 'equal to or less than' in Controller

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am pretty new to both MVC5 and C#. I have a View (List) of Supplies.  I want to do a filter on an int field 'Onhand'.  Where, the user can enter a number in the filter text box, and we bring back all supplies that are equal or less than the specified number onhand.

Here is the relevant part of my view:

```
<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index">
<p>
    Search Supplies: <input type="text" name="SearchString">
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
<p>
</p>
</form>
```

And here is where I am struggling to get things to work properly in my controller

```
var supplies = db.ICS_Supplies
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Supplies_ID)
    .ToList();

var catalogs = supplies
    .Where(s => s.OnHand.HasValue<(searchString ?? string.Empty));

var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
return View(catalogs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10));
```

Specifically . . this line here:

```
var catalogs = supplies
    .Where(s => s.OnHand.HasValue<(searchString ?? string.Empty));
```

I feel like I am almost there, but not quite understanding how to get there with `<=` the `int` value of the `searchstring`. `OnHand` is an `int?` field. Do I need to make my `searchString` an `int` as well?  Is my filter correct?

---

**Update**

This is the revised controller code . .  as of right now

```
public ActionResult Reorder(string searchString, int? page)
{
    var supplies = db.ICS_Supplies
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Supplies_ID)
        .ToList();

    var catalogs = supplies
        .Where(s => 
            s.OnHand.HasValue &&
            (searchString == null || s.OnHand.Value <= int.Parse(searchString)));

    var pageNumber = page ?? 1;

    return View(catalogs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10));
}
```

Comment: `HasValue` returns `true` if there's a value, and is only applicable to a nullable type (you state that `OnHand` is an `int`, but it must be an `int?`). To compare it to a `string`, you should convert the string to an `int`. So you would end up with something like: `supplies.Where(s => s.OnHand.HasValue && searchString != null && s.Value <= int.Parse(searchString))`

Comment: Or if you want to return values if `searchString` is `null`, it would be `s.OnHand.HasValue && (searchString == null || s.Value <= int.Parse(searchString))`. Although `int.Parse` will throw an exception if `searchString` is not an `int`, so using `TryParse` would be better.

Comment: @RufusL.  thank you for your reply.  I see what you are saying. I tried to implement var catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.OnHand.HasValue && (searchString == null || s.Value <= int.Parse(searchString));   and I am seeing two errors.  1 is telling me that there is no definition for Value.  And then (2) that searchString cannot convert from int to string.

Comment: @RufusL - I resolved the searchString convert from int to string.  But still have the 'no definition for Value' issue

Comment: OnHand is an int field

Comment: I am not sure.   What I can tell you is that OnHand is an int field, and I also just updated my original question to show you the full controller code with the changes.

Comment: With the updated code  . it is not liking the 's.Value <= int.Parse(searchString))'

Comment: I am very sorry.  It is int?  not int.  public int? OnHand { get; set; }

Comment: I'm also very sorry - it should be `s.OnHand.Value`... :)

Comment: Okay, that took away the build error . . and the view loads, but the filter is not working.  No matter what number I enter into the searchString textbox . . it still brings back ALL the records, not just the ones with the OnHand.Value of equal or less than the searchString

Comment: When parsing a string into an integer it is generally best practice to use TryParse() and check the result in order to avoid throwing an exception.  I am also confused about why you convert pageNumber into a string, then parse it back into an integer  It's never really being used as a string?

Comment: And are you certain the string is not `null` when the query is executed? That is the only case I can see where it would return all the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condensing our conversation into an answer, you stated you are having an issue with this line of code:

```
var catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.OnHand.HasValue < (searchString ?? string.Empty));
```

There are a couple of issues here. First, `HasValue` returns a `bool`, so we can't do a `<` comparison with it. Instead, if `HasValue` is `true`, then we want to do the comparison on the `Value` property:

```
var catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.OnHand.HasValue && s.OnHand.Value < searchValue)
```

However, we need to use an `int` in place of `searchValue` above, and in your original code you're using a string. So we need to convert the string to an `int`, and the safest way to do that is `int.TryParse`, which returns a `bool` indicating success, and which sets the `out` parameter to the converted value if it succeeds.

Since you said that if the string is `null` we should return all the values, then we should create a value from the string where if it's `null` it will be the maximum value. So we can do something like this:

```
int searchValue;

// If searchString is null (or not an int), then set our searchValue to int.MaxValue
if (!int.TryParse(searchString, out searchValue)) searchValue = int.MaxValue;
```

Now we can use this `searchValue` to filter our query:

```
var catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.OnHand.HasValue && s.OnHand.Value <= searchValue)
```

Comment: This is a great answer, as one slight improvement I would recommend he updates his form to use: `Search Supplies: <input type="number" name="SearchString">`.  This would remove the need to parse the SearchString variable entirely.

Comment: Thank you Rufus L, for all the time and effort you put into this.  Your answer helps me understand what is happening and why, and I appreciate that very much.  The Filter is working now. And I will mark this as solved.  There is still an issue with the pagination.  When I go to the next page of results, the filter fails and all results show again, regardless of the filter.  But, I will start that off as a new question.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer... but intended to help you, this is hard to read...

```
 public ActionResult Reorder(string searchString, int? page)
    {
        /// this has performance issues
        var supplies = db.ICS_Supplies.OrderByDescending(g => g.Supplies_ID).ToList();

         // problem here is you are checking for null, in a c# way and not linq
         var catalogs = supplies.Where(s => s.OnHand.HasValue && (searchString == null || s.Value <= int.Parse(searchString)));

        var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
        return View(catalogs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10));

    }
```

This needs more work but is easier to read... and hope it helps you

```
 public ActionResult Reorder(string searchString, int? page)
    {
        /check your string first
        if(searchString == null)
           searchString = "";

        ///from the below im guessing searchString is an int
        var int value = int.Parse(searchString);

        var supplies = db.ICS_Supplies.Where(x => x.OnHand != null 
                                && searchString.Contians(x.FieldName) 
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.Supplies_ID)
         .ToList(); // to list forces a pull of the results

       //other stuff to work on
        var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
        return View(catalogs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Reorder(string searchString, int? page)
{   
int convertInt = 0;

var catalogs = db.ICS_Supplies
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Supplies_ID)
        .ToList();

if (Int32.TryParse(searchString, out convertInt))
{
   catalogs = supplies
            .Where(s => 
                s.OnHand.HasValue &&
                s.OnHand.Value <= convertInt);
}
 var pageNumber = page ?? 1;

 return View(catalogs.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10));
}
```